# Why does on statement create a 6x6 array and other creates a 1x6 array python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

Another super noob question
why does

```
a = [["?" for i in range(6)] for i in range(6)]
```

create a 6x6 array with seperated "?"s

```
print(a)
```

gives

```
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

but

```
a = [["?" * 6] *6]
```

create a1x6 array with "?" together.

```
print(a)
```

gives

```
[['??????', '??????', '??????', '??????', '??????', '??????']]
```

How do I create the 6x6 without using the for loop in the declaration step?

Comment: You could do `[['?']*6]*6` but it is a bad way to try and create nested lists, because it actually gives you the same inner list 6 times. You're better off using the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at what you wrote.

```
a = [["?" * 6] *6]
```

The middle bit, `"?" * 6`, is a string of 6 question marks. When you put square brackets around it, you get a list containing that string, so

```
['??????']
```

Then you multiply that list by 6, giving:

```
['??????', '??????', '??????', '??????', '??????', '??????']
```

and you put the whole thing in another list

```
[['??????', '??????', '??????', '??????', '??????', '??????']]
```

Alternatively, what you might have meant to do is this:

```
[['?'] * 6] * 6
```

which does indeed give you a list sort of like you want

```
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
```

However, what this actually is is one inner list `['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']` six times in another list. So if you were to try and modify the inner elements, you would find every inner list being modified.

You are better off using the list comprehension, or a middle ground, which would be this:

```
a = [['?'] * 6 for _ in range(6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it without an explicit `for` somewhere:

```
import itertools

>>> s = '?'*6
>>> s
'??????'
>>> q = itertools.repeat(s,6)
>>> list(map(list,q))
[['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'],
 ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?']]
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> s
'??????'
>>> z = zip(*itertools.tee(s,6))
>>> list(z)
[('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'), ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'), ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'), ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'), ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?'), ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')]
>>>
```